# @Value annotation is not working correctly - SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, toggle

I am trying to implement toggle feature, but I am a bit stuck. I have a piece of code that I want it to be turned on for dev and turned off for prod.

I have put this piece of code in my `.yml` file

```
feature:
  toggles:
    checksLoginAndRegistration: true
```

And I would like to access `true` from .yml file in my class with `@Value` annotation.

```java
@Value("${feature.toggles.checksLoginAndRegistration}")
private boolean checksLoginAndRegistration;

private void validateLoginNow(LoginInfo info, User user) {
    checkKnownBlock(info, user.username);
    if(checksLoginAndRegistration){
        try {
            service.validateLogin(user.username);
        } catch (ValidationException alidationException) {
            throw new Exception(user.username);
        }
    }
}
```

But when I run my code, I can see that value is false when it should be true.

What am I missing here?

Comment: why do you have that: = true? Also, you understand that the variable we're talking about isn't a local variable?

Comment: Because if I don't, my test are failing. Now I just want to overwrite it with false from .yml file

Comment: are you working in a Spring application/context? it seems like your yaml file isn't linked. Are you running this in openshift?

Comment: Yes I am.  I wonder what am I doing wrong. I think it should work. I have read also a bit here http://dolszewski.com/spring/feature-toggle-spring-boot/

Comment: your test fails without the = true, you should remove the = true and create a separate properties/yml for your test. Have you tried that?

Comment: No I havent. Yes, my tests are failing without true. What do you mean create separate yml file for tests?

Comment: that you shouldn't have the = true. Your tests rely on that value being set to true, so you need a properties file or a yml file that sets that value as true.

Comment: Yes, I do have it. If you would read my question again. I have set up `feature:
  toggles:
    checksLoginAndRegistration: true`in .yml file but it's not being read. And I don't know why

Comment: in what kind of tests doesn't it work?

Comment: in the test of class were try/catch block should be included.

Comment: you mean a simple unit test?

Comment: yes the simple unit test is not running if i am trying to get true from .yml file

Comment: then probably your configuration of your test isn't good

Comment: Test is good. But I am not reading .yml file as I should: Because value is always false when it should be true

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the below two options:

Active the profiles based on your needs as given below in application.yaml:

spring:
profiles: dev
feature:
toggles:
checksLoginAndRegistration: true

spring:
profiles: prod
feature:
toggles:
checksLoginAndRegistration: false

spring:
profiles:
active: dev

(or)

1. Create application.yaml and define all default properties there.
2. Create application-Dev.yaml and override properties needed for the dev Environment.
3. Create application-Prod.yaml and override properties needed for the prod Environment.
4. Set spring.profiles.active by either passing it as a system property or defining it within application.yaml.
   When you are running an app with a {PROFILE}, Spring will parse application-{PROFILE}.yaml after application.yaml.

Comment: My problem is that I cant find the way to display boolean from .yml file. all of this that you have written I have set alredy